# Is there a Catkin unit test report XMLT (for pretty printing)?

Tags: ros, catkin, xml, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody come up with XMLT files to convert gtest/nosetest XML reports to a more human-readable form? I find it hard to tell at a glance if all tests passed, so something condensed and uniform would be nice. (E.g. if all lines are green, then I don't need any more detail.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101841/is-there-a-catkin-unit-test-report-xmlt-(for-pretty-printing)?/) by [b-adkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/8856/b-adkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a (ascii) summary of (failing) tests you can call `catkin_test_results path/to/test/results`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2